# Atomic operation for AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an application where I take files based on some event(SQS) and after some business logic PUT them in S3. It runs in an ECS cluster.

I want it to be robust, that is even if the container crashes the files should not be lost or should not be overridden in S3. This could happen if the container crashed and the SQS event replayed. The S3 file will be overridden.

In order to handle this scenario, I thought of making an idempotent entry for the file already processed and then PUT in S3. And before the PUT action I always check this repo. But what if the container crashes after the idempotent entry is made and before the PUT event.

I need a way in which I can ensure that these two events are atomic or they are in some sort of transaction.

Comment: If the container crashes you need how do you know that you need to reprocess that file?

Comment: The SQS event replays in this case after the visibility timeout expires.

Comment: using a expresive name for the procesed file is an option? Just something like original-filename.done and checking it before processing. I understand that once the new file is created, the task is finished so you only need to take care of the replay scenario.